# Вопрос по php и wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ajax - запрос в котором я передаю 2 переменные.
Обрабатываю этот запрос в function.php, эти 2 переменные перемножаются, проверил их по отдельности, значения обработчик получает, но когда произвожу умножение, возвращает 0. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Числа дробные если что)

Comment: Числа небось через запятую, и одно из них типа 0,5

Comment: Я более чем уверен, что $_POST['value_input'] является строкой, а не числом - для проверки можно сделать var_dump($_POST['value_input']); и там, скорее всего будет string(). Если я прав, то $_POST['value_input'] нужно заменить на (int)$_POST['value_input']

Comment: @noname228 если там точка в числе как разделитель целой и дробной части, то перемножит правильно. Ну и не (int), безусловно.

Comment: Дополнительно почитайте о wp_send_json()